# Is $k$-Clique NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory

On my lecture note it was written that "Finding a clique of size $k$ in a graph is NP".

Later in an example for reduction the following was written:

"Assume we know how to answer "Is there a clique of size $k$ in a graph", then each time we will hide one node of the graph an on the newly created graph we will check Is there a clique of size $k$ in a graph:

If there is a clique of size $k$ and the node is not a part of the clique

If there is no clique of size $k$ and the node is part of the clique

I have read more about it, and wanted to be sure I have understand this example.

1. Given a graph, answering the question whereas or not it has clique of size $k$ is NP
2. Given a graph, printing a clique of size $k$ is P

If it is correct then this is an example why NP is a problem (1) that the verifier (2) is P?

Comment: You seem to confuse to different dichotomies here. Firstly, the distinction between the (general) Clique problem where $k$ is part of the input and the family of $k$-Clique probems where $k$ is fixed for each problem. Secondly, the distinction between the decision problem of Clique and the corresponding search problem.

Comment: Please also read our reference question [What is the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard).

Comment: The k-clique problem can easily be solved in O(n^k), for every fixed k.